# XCode 6.1.1 doesn't present the keyCode Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ide, xcode6.1

After Updating XCode to version 6.1.1 today 
i lost the key Code Color from the syntax !!!
is this a bug in the XCode ? or it is something i had to deal with ?
this is the code

```
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]connectDB];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM ClientInformation"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='ClientInformation'"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM FollowUp"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='FollowUp'"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM JournalTBL"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='JournalTBL'"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM personStatusTBL"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='personStatusTBL'"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM PersonAllergyFoodsTBL"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='PersonAllergyFoodsTBL'"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM MessagesTBL"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]deleteData:@"DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='MessagesTBL'"];
[[sharedDataObject _DBObject]disconnectDB];
```

While i was expecting this 
[image]

I've got this

[image]

Comment: I believe this is related to theme...

Comment: @FahimParkar Thank you for your interest but no the xcode doesn't consider the text as objects and other staff of coding it consider the whole thing as plain text !! there is no autocomplete for the class ...

Comment: ahhh, you are facing the same problem like me... Even I don't have solution for that... that was like a bug...

Comment: @FahimParkar do you think it's related to the version of the xCode ? or the installation process ? :/ 
i can't help writing any piece of code ??
how did you deal with this problem ?